# Laravel Validation exists - multiple WHERE OR clausule

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-exists

How can I use laravel's `exists` validation rule in this case:

```
WHERE role='ADMIN' OR
WHERE role='EDITOR' OR
WHERE role='MARKETING'
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: May be this will help -http://laravel.io/forum/07-07-2014-how-to-add-or-operator-to-validation-rule